# Directed graph min-cut library

Tags: java, algorithm, scala, graph

I'm looking for a Scala (or Java) graph library implementing min-cut for directed graphs.

Is there any library you would recommend me to use?

Answer (score 2):

[JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) has one (for Java).

Check Documentation -> JUNG API Javadoc. The `edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.flows` package has [a class](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/index.html?edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/flows/EdmondsKarpMaxFlow.html) with a `getMinCutEdges()` method.

Comment: It is specifically related to the max flow problem, which is the dual of min cut, and requires to specify the source and sink vertices.
Unfortunately I don't know the optimal way to select them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Scala graph](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-graph/wiki). It doesn't look like it provides min cut in the API but you can use it to implement whatever graph algorithms you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [Tinkerpop Blueprints](http://blueprints.tinkerpop.com/) in conjunction with [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) as Blueprints has a very good interface for Graphs and a lot of Helpers for Graph I/O and Traversal whereas JUNG already has a lot Algorithms implemented.

Tinkerpop includes a class named [`com.tinkerpop.blueprints.pgm.oupl.jung.GraphJung`](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/JUNG-Ouplementation) so that you could use any Tinkerpop `Graph` inside JUNG.

For example:

```java
Graph graph = ... // construct a particular Blueprints graph implementation
PageRank<Vertex,Edge> pageRank = new PageRank<Vertex, Edge>(new GraphJung(graph), 0.15d);
pageRank.evaluate();
```